# Merge two files of different lengths in Python

Tags: python

I have two files with with the same number of columns, but a different number of rows.   One file is a list of timestamps and a list of words, the second file is a list of timestamps with a list of sounds in each of the words, i.e.,:

```
9640 12783 she
12783 17103 had
...
```

and:

```
9640 11240 sh
11240 12783 iy
12783 14078 hv
14078 16157 ae
16157 16880 dcl
16880 17103 d
...
```

I want to merge these two files and create a list of entries with the word as one value, and the phonetic transcription as the other, i.e.,:

```
[['she', 'sh iy']
 ['had', 'hv ae dcl d']
  ...
```

I'm a complete Python (and programming) noob, but my original idea was to do this by searching the second file for the second field in the first file, and then appending them into a list.  I tried doing it this way:

```py
word = open('SA1.WRD','r')
phone = open('SA1.PHN','r')
word_phone = []

for line in word.readlines():
    words = line.split()
    word = words[2]
    word_phone.append(word)

for line in phone.readlines():
    phones = line.split()
    phone = phones[2]
    if int(phones[1]) <= int(words[1]):
        word_phone.append(phone)

print word_phone
```

This is the output:

```
['she', 'had', 'your', 'dark', 'suit', 'in', 'greasy', 'wash', 'water', 'all', 'year', 'sh', 'iy', 'hv', 'ae', 'dcl', 'd', 'y', 'er', 'dcl', 'd', 'aa', 'r', 'kcl', 'k', 's', 'uw', 'dx', 'ih', 'ng', 'gcl', 'g', 'r', 'iy', 's', 'iy', 'w', 'aa', 'sh', 'epi', 'w', 'aa', 'dx', 'er', 'q', 'ao', 'l', 'y', 'iy', 'axr']
```

As I said, I'm a total noob, and some suggestions would be very helpful.

**Update:**
I'd like to revisit this question if possible.  I've modified Lattyware's code to operate on a directory:

```
phns = []
wrds = []
for root, dir, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    wrds = wrds + [ os.path.join( root, f ) for f in files if f.endswith( '.WRD' ) ]
    phns = phns + [ os.path.join( root, f ) for f in files if f.endswith( '.PHN' ) ]
phns.sort()
wrds.sort()
files = (zip(wrds,phns))

#OPEN THE WORD AND PHONE FILES, COMPARE THEM
output = []
for file in files:
    with open( file[0] ) as unsplit_words, open( file[1] ) as unsplit_sounds:
        sounds = (line.split() for line in unsplit_sounds)
        words = (line.split() for line in unsplit_words)
        output = output +  [
          (word, " ".join(sound for _, _, sound in
                    takeuntil(sounds, stop)))
                for start, stop, word in words
            ]
```

There is some information I would like to retain in the filepaths of these files.  I was wondering how I might go about appending the split file path to the tuples in the list this code returns, e.g.,

```
[('she', 'sh iy', 'directory', 'subdirectory'), ('had', 'hv ae dcl d', 'directory', subdirectory')]
```

I figured I could I could split the paths and then zip the lists together, but there are 53,000 total items in the list the code above outputs, but only 6300 file pairs being processed.

Comment: If this is homework, please add the `homework` tag.

Comment: This is actually part of a larger research program (outside of class), but thank you for the notice.

Comment: OK. Sorry for being nasty and suspicious :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a task where the main issue is matching the sounds with the words. Fortunately, this is easy to do as we can simply take all the sounds until they match the words end time.

To do this, we must construct a `takeuntil()` function - `itertools.takewhile()` (my original solution) unfortunately takes an extra value, so this is the best solution.

```
def takeuntil(iterable, stop):
    for x in iterable:
        yield x
        if x[1] == stop:
            break

with open("SA1.WRD") as unsplit_words, open("SA1.PHN") as unsplit_sounds:
    sounds = (line.split() for line in unsplit_sounds)
    words = (line.split() for line in unsplit_words)
    output = [
        (word, " ".join(sound for _, _, sound in takeuntil(sounds, stop)))
        for start, stop, word in words
    ]

print(output)
```

Gives us:

```
[('she', 'sh iy'), ('had', 'hv ae dcl d')]
```

This code uses [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for readability and closing the files (even on exceptions). It also makes a lot of use of [list comprehensions and generator expressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY).

There are some bad patterns in your code. Your use of `open()` without the `with` statement is a bad idea, and using `readlines()` isn't needed (loop directly over the file - it's lazy and therefore far more efficient in most cases, not to mention nicer to read and less to type).

So how does this work? Let's run through it:

First we  open both our files to read from, and throw in quick generator expressions to split the lines in the files.

Next comes a bit of a monster list comprehension. What we do in this is take sounds from our `sounds` iterable until we reach the last sound belonging to the word we are on, then move onto the next word, returning the word and the list of associated sounds. We then use `str.join()` to join the sounds into a single string.

If you have trouble understanding the thought process, then here is an expanded version that works the same way, albeit much less efficiently due to the python-side loops (generators and list comprehensions make the above *far* quicker):

```
with open("SA1.WRD") as words, open("SA1.PHN") as sounds:
    output = []
    current = []
    for line in words:
        start, stop, word = line.split()
        for sound_line in sounds:
            sound_start, sound_stop, sound = sound_line.split()
            current.append(sound)
            if sound_stop == stop:
                break
        output.append((word, " ".join(current)))
        current = []

print(output)
```

Comment: Wow, I think you should format that "one-liner" a bit better :) Other than that, it's pretty much what I was about to suggest, so +1

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, I'm just cleaning it up and adding explanation.

Comment: I think the `iy` is missing here, due to `takewhile` throwing away the item on which the condition is false..

Comment: Wow, thank you both for the suggestions AND the explanation.  I'm trying to learn Python, not just solve this problem :).  When the project is completed, I plan to run this over a larger corpus of data, so efficiency is key here.

Comment: Well, as @NiklasB. has pointed out, I appear to have a bug, I'll go back and take a look.

Comment: Maybe you could introduce a `takeuntil` function that essentially performs the loop in your imperative solution. I think this would be nice to have as a general utility :)

Comment: @NiklasB. The problem is that's pretty hard to implement. My gut solution is the one I've edited in, to make the sounds a list, and then use dropwhile and takewhile in unison to get the required segment. It's a little ugly, but it does work. I'll look into a cleaner solution. It's probably not hugely efficient.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of http://pastie.org/3907442 You could use your original code with that and wouldn't need to work with a list. The trick here is that we check the condition *after* yielding the item, so we don't lose one on the way.

Comment: @NiklasB. A much, much better solution, edited again to add in. I went for the simpler option of inserting the check into the function, rather than making something more general.

Comment: @Lattyware: Nice, I like that :) Keep up the great work here on SO and happy coding! I'm going to sleep now :P

Comment: This does the trick.  Again, thanks for the help and the explanations.  This has been a good introduction to StackOverflow for me.

Comment: @UWLinguist: Happy hacking to you as well :)