# Python: Compare files with similar names (recursively)

Tags: python, file-io

With the help of [these guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575686/merge-two-files-of-different-lengths-in-python), I was able to produce the following code, which reads in two files, (i.e., SA1.WRD and SA1.PHN), merges them, and compares the results against a sub-list of words excised from a dictionary:

import sys
    import os
    import re
    import itertools

```
#generator function to merge sound and word files
def takeuntil(iterable, stop):
    for x in iterable:
        yield x
        if x[1] == stop:
            break

#open a dictionary file and create subset of words
class_defintion = re.compile('([1-2] [lnr] t en|[1-2] t en)')
with open('TIMITDIC.TXT') as w_list:
    entries = (line.split(' ', 1) for line in w_list)
    comp_set = [ x[0] for x in entries if class_defintion.search(x[1]) ]

#open word and sound files
total_words = 0
with open(sys.argv[1]) as unsplit_words, open(sys.argv[2]) as unsplit_sounds:
    sounds = (line.split() for line in unsplit_sounds)
    words = (line.split() for line in unsplit_words)
    output = [
    (word, " ".join(sound for _, _, sound in
        takeuntil(sounds, stop)))
    for start, stop, word in words
]
for x in output:
    total_words += 1

#extract words from above into list of words in dictionary set
glottal_environments = [ x for x in output if x[0] in comp_set ]
```

I'm trying to modify the part after  `#open a dictionary files` to run on a large directory with several subdirectories.  Each subdirectory contains .txt files, .wav files, .wrd, and .phn files.  I want to only open .wrd and .phn files, and I'd like to be able to open them two at a time, and only if the base file name matches, i.e, SA1.WRD and SA1.PHN, not SA1.WRD and SI997.PHN.

My immediate guess was to do something like this:

```
for root, dir, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    words = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.WRD')]
    phones = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.PHN')]
    phones.sort()
    words.sort()
    files = zip(words, phones)
```

Which returns: `[('SA1.WRD', 'SA1.PHN'), ('SA2.WRD', 'SA2.PHN'), ('SI997.WRD', 'SI997.PHN')]`

My first question is whether I am on the right track, and if so, my second question is how I can go about treating each of these items in these tuples as filenames to read.

Thanks for any help you offer.

**EDIT**:

I figured I can put the block of code into a for loop:

```
for f in files:
        #OPEN THE WORD AND PHONE FILES, COMAPRE THEM (TAKE A WORD COUNT)
        total_words = 0
        with open(f[0]) as unsplit_words, open(f[1]) as unsplit_sounds:

        ...
```

However, this causes an IOError, presumably due to the single-quotes around each item in each tuple.

**Update**
I modified my original script to include `os.path.join(root, f)` as noted below.  The script now walks through all files in the directory tree, but it only processes the last two it finds.  Here is the output of `print files`:

```
[]
[('test/test1/SI997.WRD', 'test/test1/SI997.PHN')]
[('test/test2/SI997.WRD', 'test/test2/SI997.PHN')]
```

Comment: Your solution will only work if there is a perfect match between .wrd files and .phn files.  Is it possible that there will ever be a .wrd file without a corresponding .phn file, or vice versa?  If so, you'll need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Nope, in every directory this is a .wrd and a corresponding .phn file.  There are no orphans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested different parts in relation to the filesystem but it's easier for you to confirm on the actual files to confirm it works on your data.

**EDIT** to allow for inclusion of pathnames

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
import re
import itertools

#generator function to merge sound and word files
def takeuntil(iterable, stop):
    for x in iterable:
        yield x
        if x[1] == stop:
            break

def process_words_and_sounds(word_file, sound_file):
    #open word and sound files
    total_words = 0
    with open(word_file) as unsplit_words, open(sound_file) as unsplit_sounds:
        sounds = (line.split() for line in unsplit_sounds)
        words = (line.split() for line in unsplit_words)
        output = [
            (word, " ".join(sound for _, _, sound in
                            takeuntil(sounds, stop)))
            for start, stop, word in words
            ]
        for x in output:
            total_words += 1
    return total_words, output

for root, dir, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    words = [ os.path.join( root, f ) for f in files if f.endswith('.WRD')]
    phones = [ os.path.join( root, f ) for f in files if f.endswith('.PHN')]
    phones.sort()
    words.sort()
    files = zip(words, phones)
    # print files

output = []
total_words = 0
for word_sounds in files:
    word_file, sound_file = word_sounds
    word_count, output_subset = process_words_and_sounds(word_file, sound_file)
    total_words += word_count
    output.extend( output_subset )

#open a dictionary file and create subset of words
class_defintion = re.compile('([1-2] [lnr] t en|[1-2] t en)')
with open('TIMITDIC.TXT') as w_list:
    entries = (line.split(' ', 1) for line in w_list)
    comp_set = [ x[0] for x in entries if class_defintion.search(x[1]) ]

#extract words from above into list of words in dictionary set
glottal_environments = [ x for x in output if x[0] in comp_set ]
```

Comment: Thanks!  However, as per my edit above, I am still getting the IOError that it can't find the file in the directory I try to run the script on.  (IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SA1.PHN')

Comment: Have you tried the new version? I have added code to retain the full pathname with the word-sound tuples. That was the cause of the ioerror